# Android Rss Reader Library gradle integration

Tags: android-studio, gradle, rss-reader

I am trying to use this Rss reader library in android studio.But the project site does not state any gradle integration link. I searched and followed the link [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/404).  However, that link is also not working. Can anyone give me any solution to this?

https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library

Answer (score 0):

This project is very old, and it doesn't have a gradle support.

However it has only 4 classes without dependencies.
The quickest way to integrate in your project is to clone the 4 [classes](https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library/tree/master/src/nl/matshofman/saxrssreader) inside your project.